# facebook login using oauth

Tags: php, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, oauth

```
<?php
require "facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '3288@@@@@@@@@@',
    'secret' => 'ca2@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
}
?>
<?php if ($user): ?>
    <form action="#" method="get">
      NAME:  <input type="text" name="name"
            value="<?php echo $user_profile['name'] ?>"><br>
        KID'S NAME <input type="text" name="kid"><br>
        DOB <input type="text" name="kid" value="<?php echo $user_profile['birthday'] ?>"><br>
        ADDRESS <input type="text" name="kid" value="<?php echo $user_profile['email'] ?>"><br>

        KID'S GENDER 
        male<input type="radio" name="r" value="male">      
        female <input type="radio" name="r" value="male"> <br>      
    EMAIL:   <input type="text" name="name"
            value="<?php echo $user_profile['email'] ?>"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Continue &rarr;">
    </form>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLogoutUrl() ?>">
        Logout of Facebook
    </a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLoginUrl() ?>">
        Login with Facebook
    </a>
<?php endif ?>
```

I have created the app and I have the app id and secret key . Now I need whenever the new user click on the login page , it will pre filled the form pages but when I am logged in , its just showing my details and when another user logged in , its showing me nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's showing your information because you created the app and you automatically are given permission.

For others, you need your app to ask for their permission first.

The first thing you should do is this:

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream,publish_stream',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/login_approved.php'
);
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
echo '<a href="' . $url . '">Give My App Access!</a>';
```

And then create `login_approved.php` or whatever page you want to handle what happens when someone approves your app. Most notably it should record the user's access token. You will need to provide the user's access token with your app's access token to get at their information.

Comment: please can u explain me in my code . For the first time I am using this code . I will need the name , birthday , email